# MS Access: how to export to pdf in landscape orientation?

Tags: microsoft-access, orientation, landscape

I have a Pivot Chart in MS-Access which i want to export as a PDF file. How can i set the resulting PDF's orientation from portrait to landscape ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print it out using Cute PDF and set the print output to Landscape

Comment: I'm sure there's more than one workaround but I was hoping there's a simple setting in Access that controls this property.

Comment: Set the printer and report page orientation to landscape and then export it to PDF...

Comment: While printer control in Access is easier than it once was (since Access 2002), it's still not trivial, and it's kind of unpredictable. I would suggest for reliability you set up an actual report for the pivot chart, rather than try to print a form.

Answer (score 1):

When this code runs, all you see is the file save dialog.  Cute PDF must be installed according to instructions on website.

```
Dim stDocName as string
Dim prn As Printer
Dim rpt As Report

stDocName = "your report object name"

Set prn = Application.Printers("CutePDF Writer")
prn.Orientation = acPRORLandscape

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden

Set rpt = Reports(stDocName)
Set rpt.Printer = prn

DoCmd.PrintOut
DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is another way - with the view you want open switch to the file menu and choose print > print preview then select the option you want eg landscape
save this and the pdf export will remember it.

This also works for Print to PDF, whereas Save & Publish only creates in Portrait.